# IOException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream or you haven't provide the poi-ooxml*.jar

Tags: netbeans, apache-poi, inputstream, openxml, ole

I made a simple grocery program that would encode an item's name base price, taxes, markup etc. My program works by first collecting the values in the fields. then creating an excel output. if the excel file is not present it will create a new one and requires the encode button to be clicked again so the values are stored. Works well on running with NetBeans IDE but not running as a windows executable jar file. I get sorts of issues that is either caused by lack of dependencies on the jar or not identified. As of writing I am currently reading on OLE2 stream and OOXML and I don't know much. A bit of information in the comments will help. I also fixed the problem with the manifest so the program now runs and displays the gui unlike before.

```
The Main class made from NetBeans GUI.
https://pastebin.com/S89BMFf8

Second important java class
https://pastebin.com/hjnSNRRX

cmd command prompt error.
https://pastebin.com/R9kNt1se

My pom.xml file unless I have a plugin or dependency to add that you guys know about.
https://pastebin.com/9Nwt3nDx
```

EDIT: My program also runs on IntelliJ but not on it's build java form

Comment: How are you packing your program to run? How are you including your dependencies at runtime?

Comment: I am packing my program via the netbeans "clean and build" or "build with dependencies". I also made sure the manifest files include the damn dependencies on the build.

Comment: There is no need to update your question's title with "SOLVED!". I have removed that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!

replace

`Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileInputStream);`
with
`Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);`

and make sure all files produced are (.xlsx) since I am not using older version of excel files (.xls)